# Laravel Controller does not reflect changes made

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have a controller named FrontEndController.php in my Laravel 5.3 project. When I make any changes in a method, it does not reflect these changes. So, for testing i checked by making changes in other method and faced the same issue. I also created a new method in the same controller and renamed the name of method in route to the newly created method but it throws an exception that method does not exist.

So, just for testing, I renamed the controller to FrontEndController_Jan-17-2017.php and I was shocked to see that it did not throw any exception like FrontEndController.php does not exists.

Now, my question is that from where is laravel getting the FrontEndController.php file if it does not exist in actual or is there any problem of cache etc. which i'm not aware about. I have also tried by clearing the cache using php artisan cache:clear command but still not found any solution.

Route (Not contained in any group or prefix etc.)

```
Route::get('register', array('as' => 'register','uses' => 'FrontEndController@getRegister'));
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Activation;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use App\User;
use App\Contact;
use App\PNumber;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\NotActivatedException;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\ThrottlingException;
use File;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Lang;
use Mail;
use Redirect;
use Reminder;
use Validator;
use Sentinel;
use URL;
use View;
use Helper;


class FrontEndController extends JoshController
{
    /**
     * Account Register.
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function getRegister()
    {
        // Show the page
        return view('register');
    }
}
```

Comment: Any relevant code would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a namespace problem. As @pistou say, any code would be good

Comment: Thanks @manix, in my case its namespace issue.